# Less clunky way to generate properties?

Tags: python, generics, properties, getter-setter

TLDR:

What is the best way to build a class with generic property attributes and one can specify the getter and setter upon building those attributes?

Background:

I'm trying to make an object oriented representation of a SCPI command structure with Python. After parsing, the command layers are (sub-)objects and setting/getting the lowest command-object will actually communicate with a device to set/get its parameter.

The problem I encounter is the assignment of generic getter/setter functions to the command-object, acting like a property. I had a rough time with `__setattr__` / `__getattr__` as I always ran into the recursive problem.

It would be cool if there was a distinction wether an attribute is set/get during class building and in its instantiated/runtime version. Or even better: is it possible to make an attribute a property "object"? Something like:

```
foo = property()
foo.__getter__ = lambda paramName : devcontroller.request(paramName)
foo.__setter__ = lambda paramName, paramValue : devcontroller.demand(paramName, paramValue)
setattr(self, paramName, foo)
```

but apparently this is not possible (read-only).

The best solution for now is the one below, but it feels very clunky. One cannot tab-complete the command-object for instance.

```
class SCPITree(object):
    def __init__(self, cmd, branch):
        self.__dict__['building'] = True
        self.__dict__['params'] = {}
        # parse tree
        for k, v in branch.items():
            catCmd = '{}:{}'.format(cmd, k[1])
            param = k[0]
            if isinstance(v, dict):
                # still a dictionary, so unpack
                #setattr(self, param, SCPITree(catCmd, v))
                self.__dict__[param] = SCPITree(catCmd, v)
            else:
                # have the value type, so this is a leaf
                print('{} of {}'.format(catCmd, v))
                self.__dict__['params'][param] = {'cmd': catCmd, 'type': v}
                #setattr(self, param, v())

        del self.__dict__['building']

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        '''Requests the device for parameter'''
        param = self.__dict__['params'].get(name)
        if param:
            request = param['cmd']+'?'
            print('Requesting device with: {}'.format(request))
            # do actual device communication here
            return 'Response from device, converted to {}'.format(param['type'])
        else:
            if 'building' not in self.__dict__:
                raise KeyError('Device has no SCPI command for {}'.format(name))

    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        '''Sets a device parameter'''
        param = self.__dict__['params'].get(name)
        if param:
            demand = param['cmd']+' {}'.format(value)
            print('Demanding device with: {}'.format(demand))
            # do actual device communication here
        else:
            if 'building' not in self.__dict__:
                raise KeyError('Device has no SCPI command for {}'.format(name))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # test SCPI tree parsing
    trunk = {
        ('input', 'INP'):{
            ('agc', 'AGC'):{
                ('mode', 'MOD'):str, 
                ('refLevelDB', 'REF'):float}, 
            ('delayMS', 'DEL'):float, 
            ('freqMHz', 'FREQ'):float}}

    scpi = SCPITree('DCS', trunk)
```

The interaction is then something like this, after running the code:

```
DCS:INP:AGC:MOD of <type 'str'>
DCS:INP:AGC:REF of <type 'float'>
DCS:INP:DEL of <type 'float'>
DCS:INP:FREQ of <type 'float'>

In [1]: scpi.input.delayMS
Requesting device with: DCS:INP:DEL?
Out[1]: "Response from device, converted to <type 'float'>"

In [2]: scpi.input.delayMS = 3
Demanding device with: DCS:INP:DEL 3

In [3]: scpi.input.params
Out[3]:
{'delayMS': {'cmd': 'DCS:INP:DEL', 'type': float},
 'freqMHz': {'cmd': 'DCS:INP:FREQ', 'type': float}}
```

Comment: By clunky way, you mean using `__dict__`

Comment: Your question is unclear to me. What exactly do you want to accomplish?

Comment: I updated the question. Basically I'm not sure what Python syntax features exist to build a class with generic properties.